# Apache Camel - Mybatis select with parameters and useIterator

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis

I'm trying to use Apache Camel (version 2.20.0) with mybatis component.
More specifically, I have to export a large set or record from database to file.
I'd like to prevent memory issues so I want to use the option consumer.useIterator. My route is:

```
from("mybatis:selectItemsByDate?statementType=SelectList&consumer.useIterator=true")
    .split()
    .body()
        .process(doSomething)
        to(file:my-path-file);
```

but my query has in input a parameter (the starting date to get data). How should I set this parameter? 
In many example on internet I saw the parameter in the body or in the header of the Exchange message but I think is possibile only if the mybatis endpoint is in a "to" method. But the option "consumer.useIterator" is working only when the enpdoint is in a "from" method.

Please help me to understand how I can set the input for my query or if this is not supported yet (in this case if you can give some hint how to implement would be great)

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to start your route from something else, like a timer or direct endpoint, and then call the mybatis endpoint in a to, where you have set that information in the message body/header you use in the mybatis query so its dynamic.

Also you should set the splitter to be in streaming mode so it walks the iterator it gets from mybatis on-demand.